# Link with html in shiny table

Tags: html, r, shiny, hyperlink

I have a table and I'm showing a link to google which performs a search of the variable name (this works well), but now I want to perform a search using three different variables.

This is the 1 variable code:

```
createLink <- function(val) {

  sprintf('<a href="https://www.google.com/#q=%s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"> Search </a>',val)

}
```

I have tried something like this, but it is probably some kind of aberration :(

```
    createLink <- function(chr,start,end) {
sprintf('<a href="https://www.melonomics.net/melonomics.html#/jbrowse?chr="',chr,'&start=',start,'&end=', end, 'target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"> Search </a>')
}
```

My question is how can I use three variables in the html code.
I add an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1eRQ.png) of the table with the current working link.

Good bye and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there ! You can find below a working example using the 3 variables in the link construction :

```
createLink <- function(chr,start,end) {
 sprintf('<a href="https://www.melonomics.net/melonomics.html#/jbrowse? 
chr=%s&start=%s&end=%s" "target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"> Search </a>',chr,start,end)
}

#Testing the function
createLink("a","b","c")
#Result :
#[1] "<a href=\"https://www.melonomics.net/melonomics.html#/jbrowse?chr=a&start=b&end=c\" \"target=\"_blank\" class=\"btn btn-link\"> Search </a>"
```

Comment: You are too kind to me :)
Your answer works perfectly, problem solve!